# Windows Batch File to run PHP file

Tags: php

I have PHP script that fetches information from a backend server and saves into a database.

I am using wamp server and mysql. Now how do I make this run periodically (every 1 hour) without user interaction? I thought of using Windows Batch file. Is there any other way?

How do I execute a PHP file in Windows Batch file?

Comment: look for `Windows Task Scheduler`

Comment: @Joseph Silber's answer pretty much nails it. But just to throw it in, if you ever move to a hosting service, set up a cron job to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To execute PHP from a batch file, follow these 3 simple steps:

1. [Add PHP to your PATH variable](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath).
2. Create a batch file that calls PHP with your file:

   ```
   php path\to\file.php
   ```

   and name your file `whatever.bat`.
3. Now its just a matter of [setting up a task in Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson2/all/) to run your batch file periodically.